# Capturing HTML contents with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm attempting to get the contents of the current HTML document for further processing.
In useful browsers, I'm able to do this pretty easily. (See http://jsfiddle.net/HYyH4/)

Viewing that link in IE, I'm unable to get any output from that command -  "Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation."

Are there any other ways to accomplish something like this, without manually re-writing the whole DOM by hand? I'd eventually like to be able to pull it into jQuery so I can easily remove elements, so something that doesn't fail on `jQuery.html()` would be nice, too :)

Thanks for any help/feedback!

Comment: What's interesting (and annoying) about this is that when I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method", it's coming from prototype. Since I'm doing all jQuery commands, I'm not sure why anything of prototype's would even be executing. I'm fairly certain it's not as simple as a .noConflict() issue (since it's already been run).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are trying to copy the document's source, so I can't say whether the following is userful or not, however it returns an HTML element with exactly the same DOM as the original:

```
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var newDoc = doc.cloneNode(true);
alert(newDoc.innerHTML);
```

Whether that's suitable or not in your case is up to you. Note that the cloned HTML element will (depending on the browser) be missing some or all dynamically added listeners and form control values may different.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Works great in IE9; unfortunately IE8 (in which I'm also required to have it functional) gives me `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

Comment: It works in my IE 8, you are waiting until after the load event aren't you? And what is it upset about, the clone method or innerHTML property?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `documentElement` which will pull the documents root node.

> Returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for
>   example, the  element for HTML documents).

It works in IE 5.5+. Heres the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement) discussing it for further information.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/HYyH4/1/)**

Also note.. jsfiddle is not known to work well in IE at all so that could be part of the problem if thats what you are using to test with.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I get IE's /other/ error for this, which is "Invalid target element for this operation." .. I also tried using those commands directly in the Developer Tools in case it was a jsFiddle issue specifically, but same thing. :(

Comment: what version of IE, because I just tried it and it worked fine in IE9.

Comment: Weird. 9 for me as well.. no dice. It would be nice if I could just import `document.documentElement.innerHTML` to jQuery, but jQuery.html() returns a blank string.